# Puppeteer doesn't recognize selector with just type and class but accepts full selector

Tags: node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to click on a cookiewall on a webpage, but Puppeteer refuses to recognize the short selector with just the type and class selector (`button.button-action`). Changing this to the full CSS selector fixes the problem but isn't a viable solution since any chance in parent elements can break the selector. As far as I know this shouldn't be a problem because on the page in question using `document.querySelector("button.button-action")` also returns the element I'm trying to click.

The code that doesn't work:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const main = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.euclaim.nl/check-uw-vlucht#/problem", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    const cookiewall = await page.waitForSelector("button.button-action", {visible: true});
    await cookiewall.click();
};

main();
```

The code that does work:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const main = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.euclaim.nl/check-uw-vlucht#/problem", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    const cookiewall = await page.waitForSelector("#InfoPopupContainer > div.ipBody > div > div > div.row.actionButtonContainer.mobileText > button", {visible: true});
    await cookiewall.click();
};

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have three `button.button-action` there. And the first match is not visible.

[image]

One thing you could do is `waitForSelector` but without the visible bit (because it will check the first button).
And then iterate through all items checking which item is clickable.

```js
await page.waitForSelector("button.button-action");
const actions = await page.$$("button.button-action");
for(let action of actions) {
  if(await action.boundingBox()){
    await action.click();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of selecting the first clickable element found, instead of getting all and iterating them? I'm used to Selenium, where there's a wait function for "element_to_be_clickable" and the same ``button.button-action`` works. Your solution solves the issue, but unfortunately due to the structure of this website I'd have to do this probably a dozen more times. If not then thanks for the answer!

Comment: At the end of the day, the "element_to_be_clickable" from Selenium must be doing something like this. I think the perfect solution would be finding the right CSS selector. I tried to get you a good selector, but lots of its show/hide is using media queries, so I wasn't able to get a generic one. You could try being more specific without the full path, something like `actionButtonContainer.mobileText button.button.action`